# Interpret ansi escape on text file

Tags: bash, text-processing, ansi-escape

I have shell script containing:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec > >(tee -i /tmp/test.txt)
ceol=$(tput el)
echo -e "First try with tput\n=================="
echo -ne "And shes buying a"
sleep 1
echo -e "\rStairway To Heaven\n\n"
echo -e "Second try with echo\n=================="
echo -ne "Back In Black !"
sleep 1
echo -en "\r\033[0K"
echo "I hit the sack !"
```

Produce following when executed.

[image]

When I `cat /tmp/test.txt`, it would show the text rendered correctly— the same cannot be said if I view the file using `nano`. It instead output the raw text.

```
First try with tput
==================
And shes buying a^MStairway To Heaven


Second try with echo
==================
Back In Black !^M^[[0KI hit the sack !
```

Using text editor such as featherpad also exhibit same behavior.

[image]

How would I interpret/convert the output so it looks like what `cat` shows ? I want the output to be fully rendered/interpreted whether I view it with any editor, I know I can copy the output from cat-- but it's inconvenience.

```
$ cat test.txt 
First try with tput
==================
Stairway To Heaven


Second try with echo
==================
I hit the sack !
```

Comment: Do you expect the text to be rendered on the text editor? I don't think such performance should be a task of text editors. How do you `edit` the text then?

Comment: No, what I mean is there a command that can interpret all ANSI escape on text file--similar to what cat output shows.

Comment: It is not the function of the command, but the feature of the terminal which emulates
VT100 or ANSI. If you output the sequence to the system console, it will work accordingly.

Comment: @tshiono How would I do that?

Comment: Use any command which reads a file and send it to the stdout: `cat`, `head`, `tail` or whatever incuding your own program.

Comment: @tshiono I tried `cat test.txt > newfile` and its not working, `newfile` still has ansi.

Comment: Oh! Now I've understood what you want and I've found I commented in a wrong way! You want to `capture` the *visual* output after the sequence is completely output, right? Unfortunately I don't think it is possible with existing tools. My apology for bothering you so many times due to my misunderstandings.

Comment: @tshiono No worries, I already solved this.

Comment: @Liso – You ought to post your solution as an answer, so that people like me can stop looking for a solution when we find this question. ;-)